# How to run Accessibility Insights for Web for Internet Explorer based applications

Tags: internet-explorer

Our Application is designed to work in Internet Explorer10 and above only. Not compatible with Google Chrome or New Microsoft Edge. How should we run the test?

Thank you in advance.
Srinivas

Comment: What kind of test are you looking for? You can use selenium as a test tool.

Comment: Which part is not compatible with Edge and Chrome? What kind of test do you want to run? Please explain more about the details so that we can provide help accordingly. Your question is too vague.